# Python error - Error in command 'guild create' - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, csv

```
@guild.command(pass_context=True)
    async def create(self, ctx, name: str):
        """Create a guild for 70,000 gold."""
        user = ctx.message.author
        if user.id not in dev_list:
            await self.bot.say(":no_entry: This command is under constrction.")
            return
        guildmake = 0
        guildhash = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        userinfo = fileIO("data/alcher/users/{}/info.json".format(user.id), "load")
        userguild = fileIO("data/alcher/guilds/guilds.json", "load")
        if userinfo["gold"] >= 0:
            if user.id not in userguild:
                userguild[user.id] = [name, guildhash]
                userinfo["gold"] = userinfo["gold"] - guildmake
                fileIO("data/alcher/guilds/guilds.json", "save", userguild)
```

Gives me this:

```
Error in command 'guild create' - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**userguild[user.id] = [name, guildhash]** < this gives me error. It is telling me I cant use the string.

Can someone help me please!?

Comment: That error implies that `userguild` is a list and `user.id` is a string. Are those both expected things?

Comment: they should be. can u help

Comment: If `userguild` is a list then you can't use a string inside brackets - lists expect numerical indices for their indexes. If `user.id` is intended to be a number, you can pass it to `int()` - `int(user.id)`